# Use definite integrals to calculate a sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to calculate $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{2}{n^2} + \cdots + \frac{n-1}{n^2}\right)$$ by use of definite integrals. I have written the sum as $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{k}{n} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \tag{1}$$ Then I note that the Riemann sum is $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k) \Delta (x_k)$$ But now I have trouble converting $(1)$ into a definite integral. First of all, my sum goes from $k=1$ to $n-1$, whereas the Rienmann sum goes up to $n$ and then I am not sure how to find the limits of my integral. Any help or tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the $k=n$ term is missing is negligible, as its contribution is small when $n \to +\infty$.

The function being sampled in your sum is the identity function $f(x)=x$. Early values of $k$ correspond to near-zero values of $x$, while $k \approx n$ gives $x \approx 1$. Thus in the limit we obtain the integral
$$ \int_{0}^1 x \mathrm{d} x= \frac{1}{2}. $$

Comment: Can you explain your limits a bit more please? I don't quite understand

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove As $k$ goes from $1$ to $n-1$, $x_k=k/n$ goes from $1/n$ which is near $0$, to $(n-1)/n$ which is near $1$.